# HTML Javascript File Upload

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

I have following HTML object with file

```
  <form name='file_form' class="panel-body">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" />
    <input type='button' id='btnSendFile' value='sendFile' />
    <output id="list"></output>
  </form>
```

Where using the file browse in type="file", I select a file to upload.  When I click on btnSendFile, the file name of the selected file appears under name.  However file variable is null when I pass it below. I need to access file object properties of file object.

I have a function that sends the file.

```
var file ;

function sendFile(file) {
var to = $('#to').get(0).value;
var filename = file.name;
var filesize = file.size;
var mime = file.type;

}

$('#btnSendFile').bind('click', function() {
 sendFile(file);
});
```

How do I get the file object in javascript where I need to file.name, file.size, and file.type? What should I assign variable file ?

**UPDATE:**
*Answer:*

```
file= $("#file")[0].files[0];
```

Comment: Where do you invoke `sendFile` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre see the fuction above I just updated it..

Comment: You are not passing any argument in `sendFile();`

Comment: @RayonDabre I want to know how to link the file just uploaded to file variable as file object with three properties (.name, .size, and .type) shown.

Comment: Is file uploaded on server ?

Comment: You want a option in your form for file upload ??

Comment: Are you asking this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/qxm95neb/

Comment: @RayonDabre I was missing file arguments for sendFile(file).  The file is still in client side. The input type="file" id="file" is not setting the file object.

Comment: you can try alter the line: **sendFile();** to **sendFile($('#file'));**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this.previousElementSibling.files[0]` or `$("#file")[0].files[0]` to `sendFile`

```js
// var file;

function sendFile(file) {
  // var to = $('#to').get(0).value;
  var filename = file.name;
  var filesize = file.size;
  var mime = file.type;
  $("#list").html(filename + " " + filesize + " " + mime)
}

$("#btnSendFile").bind("click", function() {
  sendFile(this.previousElementSibling.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form name='file_form' class="panel-body">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" />
  <input type='button' id='btnSendFile' value='sendFile' />
  <output id="list"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you.  I just have to pass in $("#file")[0].files[0] to sendFile.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is your answer

```
 <form name='file_form' class="panel-body">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]"/>
        <input type='button' id='btnSendFile' value='sendFile' onclick="myFunction()" />
        <output id="list"></output>
      </form>

    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("file");
    var txt = "";

                var file = x.files[0];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                }
    document.getElementById ("list").innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: why do you use multiple?

Comment: I see name="file[]" in your code so i think you need to upload more then 1 file